# How can we show Custom UI when addNewIncomingCall using Connection service?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service, android-connectionservice, telecom-manager

I am trying to implement the ConnectionService.
When I add new incoming call I get the system UI to receive or to reject a call.

```
var handle = account.accountHandle
        val extras = Bundle()
        extras.putParcelable(TelecomManager.EXTRA_PHONE_ACCOUNT_HANDLE, handle)
        val manager = getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE) as TelecomManager

        manager.addNewIncomingCall(handle, extras)
```

I register the account like this

```
   fun registerConnectionService() {
        val manager = getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE) as TelecomManager
        val connectionServiceId = getConnectionServiceId()
        val componentName =
            ComponentName(applicationContext, PhoneConnectionService::class.java)
        val phoneAccountHandle = PhoneAccountHandle(componentName, connectionServiceId)
            val builder = PhoneAccount.builder(
                phoneAccountHandle,
                this.resources.getText(R.string.app_name)
            )
            val uri = Uri.fromParts("tel", "123456789", null)
            builder.setSubscriptionAddress(uri)
            builder.setAddress(uri)
            builder.setCapabilities(PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_CALL_PROVIDER)

            builder.setShortDescription("Short description")
            phoneAccount = builder.build()
            manager.registerPhoneAccount(phoneAccount)
        
    }
```

I know that to give custom UI i need to set this

```
builder.setCapabilities(PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_SELF_MANAGED)
```

ConnectionService code when receive the call

```
@Override
    public Connection onCreateIncomingConnection(PhoneAccountHandle connectionManagerPhoneAccount, ConnectionRequest request) {
        final CallConnection connection = new CallConnection(this);

        Bundle extras = new Bundle();

        connection.setAddress(request.getAddress(), PRESENTATION_ALLOWED);
        connection.setVideoState(VideoProfile.STATE_AUDIO_ONLY);
        connection.setExtras(extras);
        connection.setConnectionCapabilities(Connection.CAPABILITY_SUPPORT_DEFLECT);
        connection.setRingbackRequested(true);
        connection.setRinging();

        return connection;
    }
```

but still this method not getting called in my CallConnection class which extend the Connection.

> onShowIncomingCallUi

**Any solution that How can I implement the Custom UI using ConnectionSerivice?**

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

Actually I was doing this. (i.e setting Connection Capabilities)

> connection.setConnectionCapabilities(Connection.CAPABILITY_SUPPORT_DEFLECT);

instead I replace that with (i.e set Connection Properties)

> connection.setconnectionProperties(Connection.PROPERTY_SELF_MANAGED);

and it start calling onShowIncomingCallUi.